# Overhead of time command in unix

Tags: bash, unix, time, overhead, unix-timestamp

i was wondering what is the overhead of using the time command in unix.

i know how to use it, but i want to know how much longer the command

```
$ time java HelloWorld
```

takes on a terminal, than the command

```
$ java HelloWorld
```

I am **specifically** interested in how this overhead varies with the time duration of the program that is running.

context:: 
I am using it to measure the time taken for a bunch of long running experiments written in Java.

Comment: For `zsh`, running `time` without arguments takes `0.07s`. The overhead is minuscule.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The overhead is fixed and, based on the [source code](http://fossies.org/dox/time-1.7/time_8c_source.html), is only due to the fact that an extra process is being started (the `time` process itself), introducing a small amount of extra processing <sup>(a)</sup>. Normally, the shell would start your program but, in this case, the shell starts `time` and `time` starts your process (with a `fork`).

This extra processing involves:

- argument processing.
- the time taken to `fork` and `exec` the child.

While the process being measured is running, `time` itself is simply waiting for it to exit (with a `wait` call) so has no impact on the process.

So, while the *start-up time* for the `time` process is actually included in the measurements, these will only be significant for very short processes. If your process runs for an appreciable amount of time, the overhead of `time` is irrelevant.

As to what I mean by appreciable, you can see the effect `time` has by running it with a very fast executable, and also see if it has any appreciable increase in overhead for longer-running processes:

```
pax> time sleep 0
real    0m0.001s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s

pax> time sleep 1
real    0m1.001s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s

pax> time sleep 10
real    0m10.001s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.004s

pax> time sleep 100
real    1m40.001s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
```

In other words, hardly any effect at all.

Now, since you're only likely to be timing processes if they're long-running (it's hard to care whether a single process takes one or two milliseconds unless you're running it *many* times in succession, in which case there are better ways to increase performance), the fixed overhead of `time` gets less and less important.

---

<sup>(a)</sup>: And, if you're using a shell with `time` built in (such as `bash` with its `time` reserved word), even that small overhead disappears.

Comment: `time` is actually a shell builtin -- at least in Bash, and perhaps others.

Comment: Wouldn't it be more accurate to do `time time` to see its impact?

Comment: Is it safe to assume that a process that is constantly starting other processes won't be affected either?  e.g. ocrmypdf creates a tesseract process for each page of a PDF document when it's OCR'ing it.

Comment: @Adam, there is a non-zero (but usually small) cost in starting a process. This is mostly irrelevant for `time` since it starts only *one* process and that's *usually* relatively long-lived. If you have a process that starts a thousand other processes every single second, you will most likely see an impact. That's why using a `while read` loop in `bash` to act on one input line at a time (with an external process) is often slower than just kicking up a single `sed/awk/perl` to handle the entire input stream in one hit.

Answer (score 3):

Overhead of `time` should be fairly constant regardless of the program being timed. All it has to do is take a timestamp, run the program, take another timestamp and output a result.

In terms of accuracy etc: the shorter the program you are running is, the more impact `time` will have on it. e.g. time on "Hello World" is probably not going to give you good results. time on something that runs for a decent period will be very accurate since time's overhead will be well down in the noise.

Comment: yeah... i did read about the noise from other questions that were asked about the time command and like i said i am using this to measure the times of a few long running experiments written in java. I just wanted to make sure that the time command itself does not add to the already long running programs. Thanks for your answer!